# Vue: how to set image property as an src attribute on an async object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and still learning the ropes. I currently am fetching data from an endpoint and it's returning an object. The object is successfully making it into the component (it's showing up in the devtools and on the page, see the `p` tag in `template`.) However, despite the fact that all the data is there, I have no idea how I am supposed to access the url property that exists on the info object. Everything I've tried so far has failed to work.

Here is the error message:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null`

Is there some other approach or lifecycle method im supposed to use for async behaviors?

```
<template>
  <div class="SpaceImage">
    <img :src="info.url" />
    <p>{{info}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { API_KEY } from "../../API_KEY/API_KEY";

export default {
  name: "SpaceImage",
  data() {
    return {
      info: {},
      imnageData: ''
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.SpaceImage {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Kevin!
There can be a few moments, related to your problem. 
One is that @helikat_ sugggested, and the second is
`.then(response => (this.info = response.data))`

You need to get `data` property from the response object. It contains the response content.

Comment: I just realized that myself ... I thought it was a problem related to Vue but it was actually my fault. Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the `this` value before your axios call.

```
created() {
const vm = this;
axios
  .get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
  .then(response => (vm.info = response.data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: No need to capture `this` when using an arrow function